# Changing pixels in Image

Tags: c#, wpf, image, graphics, bitmap

I have program in which i want to do some graphic algorithms. I found some code snippets for C# that works on bitmaps. To change pixel or something like that do i have to convert image to bitmap first or is there some methods to change pixels in Image? Something like `image1.SetPixel(29,201, color1);` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `WriteableBitmap` class to create a bitmap whose pixels you can modify.

You can then set that Bitmap as the Source for an Image element.

- http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=nYl7J7z3KssC&pg=PA416&lpg=PA416&dq=wpf+writeablebitmap&source=bl&ots=V533ojV65x&sig=KJeSje1WCXaS_MT78cR4PPZMFio&hl=en#v=onepage&q=wpf%20writeablebitmap&f=false
- http://www.i-programmer.info/programming/wpf-workings/527-writeablebitmap.html?start=1
- http://www.nerdparadise.com/tech/csharp/wpfimageediting/

There's a 3rd party library which can help working with `WriteableBitmaps` more natural i.e. SetPixel and GetPixel methods instead of having to calculate offsets to the pixel data in the buffer.

- http://writeablebitmapex.codeplex.com/

Comment: How can i add WriteableBitmap to my XAML project? Instead of Canvas?

Comment: You use the WriteableBitmap in code behind, then you place the Image/Bitmap that it is managing as the Source in an Image element. See this example: http://www.nerdparadise.com/tech/csharp/wpfimageediting/